# Is it possible to called angular service in separate js file in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-chrome-extension

I would like to create a simple **chrome extension**, which can save some sentence on database. Application is written in **Angular4** with using **Firebase** to authentication. API is set up on NodeJS server.

On home page, user has ability to login by Google or Facebook account. If user is logged in, the page with saved sentences is displayed for him. On this page he can add some sentence manually too (by form).

User can save some sentence from any page using contextMenu. At this moment, if user mark and try sentence, it will showing as alert. It's implemented in this way:

part of **manifest.json**

```
...
"background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": ["home.js", "context-menu.js"]
},
...
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus"
],
...
```

and **context-menu.js**

```
var addSentence = function(info, tab) {
    console.log(info, tab);
    alert(info.selectionText);
};

var parent = chrome.contextMenus
  .create(
    {
      "title": "Add \"%s\"",
      "contexts": ["selection"],
      "onclick": function(info, tab) {
        addSentence(info);
      }
    }
  );
```

If you add sentence manually yo called **Angular service**

**sentence.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class SentenceService {

  private url = '/sentence';
  private token;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.user.subscribe(user => {
      this.token = user.uid;
    });
  }

  addSentence(sentence: Sentence) {
    const payload = sentence;
    payload.user = this.token;
    this.post(payload);
  }

  private post(sentence: Sentence) {
    return this.http
      .post(`${this.url}`, sentence)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured", err);
        }
      );
  }

}
```

As seen above, To sentence is added user token. Its important to getting sentence for user.

**Question:** 
Is it possible to called angular service in separate js file (context-menu.js)? Possibly, is it possible to getting logged user in this file? Or maybe I should added token until in nodeJS server? is it possible to catch session or something?

Comment: You don't actually show us how you are including *sentence.service.ts* in your project, so there is no way for us to actually *know* what's going on. Right now we just have to assume that it's in *home.js*. Please provide a complete, but minimal [mcve].

Comment: Questions asking "Is there a way to do X / Can I do X? / Is it possible to do X?" are rarely appropriate for the Stack Exchange format. The answer is usually "yes", but sometimes "no". Either way, the question is usually not very effective. In addition, what is usually meant is "How can I do X?", which will often, but not always, be too broad for the Stack Overflow format. In this question, it really feels like this is a debugging question (you wrote code that's not working the way you want), which is being stated as a "is it possible"/how-to question. Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: If this is a debugging question, then please also provide the actual error message which you are getting, describe what you are expecting it to do and what it is actually doing.

Comment: If your question really is something like: "In my *context-menu.js*, can I call functions that I define in *home.js*", then the answer is: The contents of the files are placed into the same scope. Thus, as long as the function defined in *home.js* is accessible through the global scope (e.g. not in a separate IIFE), then, yes, you can access it.